# User Must Enter Skills Seperated By Commas In A List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this input field: `<%= f.text_field :skills %>` and I would like to have my user list up to 5 skills (or words). Each separated by commas.

FYI, :skills is currently just one column in my Users table.

How would I accomplish this? I'm thinking somehow it would first need to separate spaces as words, put a limit on that, then combine them by commas.

Comment: Not sure what the question is; if the user has to enter it separated by commas, and that's how you want it stored, what's the problem? Are you asking how to validate it?

Comment: Yes, I guess the question is more about how to validate it and make sure the user is entering it in that format.

Comment: While I think people answer your question below, I'd urge you to rethink your design.  It's fine to have someone enter 5 skills that are comma delineated, but you'll be able to leverage better built in rails functionality if you create a skills table and let your users have many of them.

Answer (score 0):

To validate it, what about adding a format validation test in the class?

```
    class Test
      validate :valid_skills_format?

      def valid_skills_format?
        if !(self.skills =~ /regex_for_5_words_separated_by_commas/)
          self.errors.add(:skills, "wrong format")
        end
      end
    end
```

You could as well test with a split(',') and check if you have 5 results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, something like this should give you what you want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :raw_skills
  validate :five_or_fewer_skills?


  def five_or_fewer_skills?
    if unpacked_skills.size > 5
      self.errors.add(:skills, "Too many skills!")
    end
  end

  def unpacked_skills
    skills.split(',')
  end

  def pack_skills(raw)
    skills = raw.join(',')
  end
end
```

Then, on your create form, change your "skills" field to a "raw_skills" field, and during the create process say `pack_skills(raw_skills)` and that'll set your skills to the comma-serialized value. Then your validator will unpack the skills, check 'em for size, and you're good to go!